# Keep modal dialog open on page submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and a table . One of the columns in the table is a button to edit the row. I have to open a modal dialog on click of the button and the dialog would contain another table whose result set is based on the row where i have clicked the button. I need the page to submit and open a modal dialog when i click a button on each row of the table. currently when page submit happens , modal is going off. below is my script

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function() {// button is the first column   
                                             // in each row
pid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
document.getElementById('text').value =pid; // Modal dialog table result set      
                                            // depends on this pid
$("#getuser").submit(); // form (if we dont submit dialog is not show the 
                        // result set for current pid selected. instead  
                        // showing the old pid    
$( "#exe-scroll" ).dialog({ // dialog
   maxWidth:600,
                maxHeight: 500,
                width: 700,
                height: 500,
        resizable:true,
        modal: true,

   close: function() {

  });
 });
```

How to submit the page and open a modal dialog which would show the record set for the current pid selected.
Thanks in advance

Comment: when you normally submit a form page reload will happen and the document will be loaded again. If you want to keep the modal open you need to try to do an ajax posting

Comment: Exactly I'm looking for Ajax posting . Could you please guide me

Comment: what backend coding you are working into??

Comment: I'm using nodejs to pull data from mongoDb . When user clicks on edit button , i would like to send the primary key column of that table to database and based on that it nodejs would fetch data from another table.If you would like to look over the nodejs script i can share it

Comment: Don't have much idea on `node.js` !! But I can explain you how you can do it with ajax!

Comment: Thanks ..That would be helpful ..go ahead !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78152/discussion-between-sasidharan-and-guruprasad-rao).

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I will try to explain as much as possible!

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function() {
      pid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
      $.ajax({
             url:'/ServerSideFunction/', //Call a serverside function which accepts pid as parameter and retrieves the details from database and return data of type json from the same,
             type:'POST',
             dataType:'json',//return type from server side function [return it as JSON object]
             contentType: "application/json",
             data: JSON.stringify(pid), //Pass the data to the function on server side
             success: function (data) { //Result object _[say user object]_ returned from server side function and then call modal on success
                      $( "#exe-scroll" ).dialog({ // dialog
                             maxWidth:600,
                             maxHeight: 500,
                             width: 700,
                             height: 500,
                             resizable:true,
                             modal: true,
                             close: function() {

                             });
                      });  
              },
              error:
                    function (data) {
                    //display any unhandled error
              }
      });
});
```

Now if you want to set the data to the table inside the modal then you can do it on success either before modal open or after it!! The basic point here is you need return proper object of details from server side function and manipulate it through `jquery`

Comment: .I tried it and when I inspected the element ,its skipping the ajax line. hence nothing is happening . It skips and goes to the last line

Comment: In your console it actually does that!! You need to put a breakpoint [if available] on your server side code and check whether that function is getting hit or not!!